# Take screenshot of specific plot in a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, shinyscreenshot

How do I take a screenshot of a specific plotly chart in a shiny app and not the whole UI?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyscreenshot)
library(plotly)

ui <- fluidPage(
  plotlyOutput("plot"),
  actionButton("go", "Take a screenshot")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot<-renderPlotly({
    
    fig <- plot_ly(
      x = c("giraffes", "orangutans", "monkeys"),
      y = c(20, 14, NA),
      name = "SF Zoo",
      type = "bar"
    )
    
    fig
  })
  observeEvent(input$go, {
    screenshot()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `selector` argument:

> By default, the entire page is captured. If you'd like to capture a specific part of the screen, you can use the selector parameter to specify a CSS selector. For example, if you have a plot with ID myplot then you can use screenshot(selector="#myplot")

In this case :

```
screenshot(selector="#plot")
```